# C# Get notified when removing an application in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

Is there any way to get notified when user is removing an application from add/remove programs in control panel? I saw there is an [API in Windows CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms840679.aspx), but not in Windows 7. I would like to get notified in Windows 7 by using C#, thanks!

Comment: I could be mis-reading the API you've linked to, but I think it's referring to functions called on the application being installed/uninstalled. The rest of your question reads more as wanting to know when *other* applications are uninstalled. Could you clarify your question if this is the case? (If you only care about your own application, you could look at custom actions in MSIs)

Comment: Yes, I would like to know when all other applications are uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created an installer in visual studio there is an object model to extend the installation and uninstallation logic.

See this link for a further explanation [Code project installer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/ExtendVSSetupProject.aspx)

This won't work for any other uninstalls but the given application.

Comment: Thanks Barfieldmv, that gives me another thought. But I still need to be notified when other applications are uninstalled. Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in control of the uninstall process you can notify yourself however you please during that process. But there's no magic API to do the work for you I'm afraid.